# com.google.android.maps

Tags: android, google-maps, grid, android-mapview, keystore

Since few days my application does not show maps anymore.
To make sure my code is right, I decided to test the MAPS Tutorials 
application found in developer.android.com [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

The maps on the tutorial does not show either. 
I just see the usual little grids of the Mapview. 
When I tap it I have the normal response telling me the corresponding Geocodes.

Any idea why ??

The code of the tutorial is this one:

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity
```

{

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my key"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally if your map only shows a grid and no tiles you are mixing a release apk with a debug api key or vice-versa.

Comment: You are certainly right. Two or three days ago Eclipse told me that my debug.keystore was obsolete. I read somewhere that I just had to erase it and a new one would be generated. It is probably since then that I can only see the grid of my MapView. But I don't see the link between my apiKey for Maps and the debug.keystore.

Comment: Of course: Go now to get a key. For instructions, read Obtaining a Maps API Key. For the purpose of this tutorial, you should register with the SDK debug certificate, which will only be valid while your application is signed with the debug key (once you sign with your private key, you will need a new API key). When you get your key, insert it for the value of android:apiKey. THANKS!

Comment: $ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android